# Symfony + Doctrine Many to Many relations with Linking Tables

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many

Situation:

I have 3 tables: Student, Address, StudentAddressLink As follows Note* not EXACT yaml file but you get the idea

```
Student:  
 column:  
  id: blah blah  
  name: blah blah  
Address:  
 column:  
  id: ~  
  street: ~  
StudentAddressLink:  
 column:  
  id:~  
  student_id: ~  
  address_id: ~  
 relations:  
  Student:  
    local: student_id  
    foreign: id  
   Address:  
     local: address_id  
     foreign: id
```

From the Student object I want to get the related "Address Street" 
currently I have to do this:

```
foreach($student->StudentAddressLink as $address)
{
    echo $address->getStreet();
}
```

This works...but I though there was a way to do something that makes the link table transparent, something magical like this:

```
foreach($student->Addresss as $address)
{
  echo $address->getStreet();
}
```

Any direction would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want many-to-many relations, you need to use something like the code [here](http://www.symfony-project.org/doctrine/1_2/en/04-Schema-Files#chapter_04_sub_many_to_many) (for an out of date version of symfony but still correct).

This involves setting the `refClass` as `StudentAddressLink`, allowing the transparent relationship that you want.  You will then be able to use `$student->Address[0]->getStreet`, for example.  The documentation there can explain better than I can!

---

**Edit** I think your schema needs to look something like this:

```
Student:  
  columns:   
    name: string
  relations:
    Address:
      refClass: StudentAddressLink
      local: student_id
      foreign: address_id
Address:  
  columns:  
    street: ~
StudentAddressLink:  
  columns:  
    student_id: ~  
    address_id: ~
```